# Form Library in publishing Portal

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I want to create a Forms Library on a Publishing Portal.

Should I edit the Site Definition / is there any other way to get a Forms Library?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the Enterprise Features feature.. in your site collection root go to Site Settings, Site collection features and Activate the "Office SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" feature.

This will give you the forms library as a list type you can create through Site Actions, View All Site Content, Create. (amongst other things)

Comment: For me it was "Team Collaboration Lists" feature in the "Site Features". Thanks for the pointer Arjan